# Help Identifying Mega Bloks Parts

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

[image]

I've bought a storage unit, and truly have no idea what these *Mega Bloks* are a part of.

There are two blue domes, two green domes, and a bunch of what looks like tracks/road pieces.

Answer (score 5):

**Brand**: *MEGA BLOKS*.

**Set Theme**: *Planetoids*.

**Set Name**: *LX-009 City*.

**Year**: *1997*.

[image]

[image]

**BIG THANKS** to *[Gnovice](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/444/gnovice)* for the positive I.D. on the track piece, which proved it was at least from the *MEGA BLOKS* line, but just in a different color.

- Color discrepancy note: I think the *Original Poster's* camera flash turned the darker purple color of the pieces into a blueish hue.

Comment: Nice! Guess I should have been looking [here](http://bricker.info/osets.html?brand=megabloks) instead.

Comment: Hey, you've been the greatest of Luck Dragons.  Today you've given me two new places to look.  Just when I thought I've reached the boundaries of Fantasia/ the Internet, you provide me with more.  BIGGER THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

Those track pieces appear to resemble in shape (if not in color) the track pieces in set [9801 Build & Race Speedway](http://www.blokcity.com/wiki/9801_Build_%26_Race_Speedway):

[image]

No idea about the "domes". Could they be lids to containers?